# How to check if dropdown is open in Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) and in my site. I need to know at some point if the dropdown is open or closed. I've studied the [documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation) but I don't see how this can be done. For example, something like this would be nice:

```
if ($('select').select2('isOpen') === true) { ... }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: it surely adds a class when it is open, debug it and see wich class it adds, then use some jquery ('#myselect theClassIFound')

Comment: It just changes the html attribute style="display: block/none;" so play with that and use some jquery to detect that change

Comment: I don't see anything happening on the select element. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUsMb/2701/).

Comment: I am not sure why fiddles does not show it but if you debug your browser you will see it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By doing some code inspection, it looks like `select2-dropdown-open` is the class that it adds. But there is an event `select2-open` in the documentation that fires when the dropdown is open. You can use that to set a variable, or perform an action (also `select2-close`).

You can do something like this:

```
$("#e11").on("select2-open", function() { 
    $(this).data("open", true);
});
$("#e11").on("select2-close", function() { 
    $(this).data("open", false);
});

if ($("#e11").data("open")) {
    //do something
}
```

**2018 Edit**

It appears that the names of the events have been updated since 2014. [See user1636505's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30946064/579148).

Comment: the class `select2-dropdown-open` is not added to the select element itself! I noticed that there is an event fired, but I hoped for a better solution

Comment: `'select2:open'` is the event

Answer (score 19):

In version 4.0 of `select2` you can listen to `select2:opening`, `select2:open`, `select2:closing` and `select2:close` events on `select` element, for example:

```
$('select').on('select2:open', function (e) {
    // select2 is opened, handle event
});
```

Comment: `select2:close` to do the opposite

Comment: Does not work for multiple

Answer (score 14):

Select2 4.0 has an `isOpen` method.  If `#mySelect` is your HTML select element then:

```
$('#mySelect').data('select2').isOpen()
```

...will return true or false depending on the state of Select2.

Comment: $('#mySelect').data('select2') is not available on jQuery v3.6.0, select2 v4.1.0.

Answer (score 8):

As of Select2 4.0.6, this has been updated to the following

```
$("#foo").select2("isOpen")
```

This will return true/false

Hope this helps!

Comment: This returns "undefined" on jQuery v3.6.0, select2 v4.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

`change` is fired whenever an option is selected or removed.

`select2:open` is fired whenever the dropdown is opened. select2:opening is fired before this and can be prevented.

`select2:close` is fired whenever the dropdown is closed. select2:closing is fired before this and can be prevented.

`select2:select` is fired whenever a result is selected. select2:selecting is fired before this and can be prevented.

`select2:unselect` is fired whenever a result is unselected. select2:unselecting is fired before this and can be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to do this:

```
var select2 = $('#selectorname').data('select2');
if (select2.opened()) {
        //do it
    } else {
        //dont do it
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$('select').select2('isFocused');

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/39

Answer (score -1):

It works perfectly.

```
$(".select2-container").is(":visible")
```